# Facebook SDK v4 for android doesn't send app invites

Tags: android, facebook

I send app invites through the Facebook SDK v4 on Android.
In case when the recipient is in my Roles-Testers, the notification is generated. 
In other cases, no notification is generated on the user's side.

I can not find the relevant documentation.
In Status&Rewiev menu of my applicaton there is the option "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" (at the moment - no).
I suppose the Facebook requires my application to be submitted for Approval.
If so, what items should I include in this submission? Have you sent .apk file?

Comment: Your app of course need to be Live otherwise other people can't see the app. And no you don't need to submit it to take it live

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much.